# use opengl in thread

Tags: opengl

I have a library, which is engaged in rendering on opengl and prinimaet streams from the network.

I write under a poppy, but plans to use on linux

so the window is created for objective c
I start drawing in a separate thread in the other receiving and decoding the data.

I crash bug (EXT_BAD_ACCESS) on methods of opengl, even if I use them only in a single thread.

my code
main glut:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGBA);
int win = glutGetWindow();
glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
glutCreateWindow("OpenGL lesson 1");
client_init(1280, 720, win, "192.168.0.98", 8000, 2222);
return 0;
```

}

or objective c

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect pixelFormat:(NSOpenGLPixelFormat*)format{
self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];
if (self != nil) {
    NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute attributes[] = {

        NSOpenGLPFANoRecovery,
        NSOpenGLPFAFullScreen,
        NSOpenGLPFAScreenMask,
        CGDisplayIDToOpenGLDisplayMask(kCGDirectMainDisplay),
        (NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute) 0
    };
    _pixelFormat = [[NSOpenGLPixelFormat alloc] initWithAttributes:attributes];
    if (!_pixelFormat)
    {
        return nil;
    }
    //_pixelFormat   = [format retain];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(_surfaceNeedsUpdate:)
                                                 name:NSViewGlobalFrameDidChangeNotification
                                               object:self];
    _openGLContext = [self openGLContext];
    client_init(1280, 720, win, "192.168.0.98", 8000, 2222);
}
return self;
```

}

client_init code

```
    // pthread_create(&posixThreadID, NULL, (void*(*)(void*))ShowThread, dh_tmp);
pthread_create(&posixThreadID, NULL, (void*(*)(void*))ShowThread, NULL);

void* ShowThread(struct drawhandle * dh){

        //glViewport(0, 0, dh->swidth, dh->sheight);//EXT_BAD_ACCESS
        glViewport(0, 0, 1280, 720);//EXT_BAD_ACCESS

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        //gluOrtho2D(0, dh->swidth, 0, dh->sheight);
        gluOrtho2D(0, 1280, 0, 720);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();

    ...
        return 0;
    }
```

I think the problem is? that uncreated context opengl.

How to create it in macos / linux?

Comment: Sure that `dh` isn't null?

Comment: yeah sure, it was the first version

Comment: Hi, have you created the opengl context? if not tell me what os and I can try and throw some code together to let you see whats needed :)
Also what APIs/libraries are you using? ie CGL/GLEW/GLUT etc

Comment: I created NSOpenGLContext and without trying.
there is also a version with glud.

Comment: added the line CGLContextObj context = CGLGetCurrentContext (); before init opengl! Now there is no error, but draws excerpts from the desktop http://joxi.ru/M6Q1LBRB

Comment: int set_current_context(struct drawhandle * dh){
    CGLSetCurrentContext(dh->context);
    return 0;
}

starting from the stream set_current_context method solves the problem on mac os

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This thread has no current OpenGL context. Even if you did create a context earlier in the program (not visible in your snippet), it will not be current in the thread you launch.

An OpenGL context is always, with no exceptions, "current" for exactly one thread at a time.  By default this is the thread that created the context. Any thread calling OpenGL must be made "current" first.

You **must** either create the context in this thread, or call `glXMakeCurrent` (Unix/Linux) or `aglMakeCurrent` (Mac) or `wglMakeCurrent` (Windows) inside `ShowThread` (before doing anything else related to OpenGL).

*(probably not the reason for the crash, though... see datenwolf's answer for the likely reason of the crash -- nevertheless it's wrong)`*

Comment: This thread has no current OpenGL context.
I think it is, how do I create or connect? Show me the code please!

Comment: @user1881371: To post some usefull code, we first need to see your code. In particular your program startup and how you create your window and a OpenGL context attached to it.

Comment: @user1881371: The 5-6 lines of GLUT code that you posted above in your edit do create a context. However, it is current in the main thread, which means it is _not_ current in the thread created by `phtread_create`. This is, again, not the likely reason for the crash (immediate mode normally doesn't crash, it just doesn't work -- so datenwolf's idea that the `dh` pointer might be null is a good guess), but not having a current context is incorrect and will be the reason for _"it doesn't work, I can't figure why"_ once you've fixed the crash.

Comment: dh do with it, I checked! and even removed it from the example, all the same (((
added the line CGLContextObj context = CGLGetCurrentContext (); before init opengl! Now there is no error, but draws excerpts from the desktop joxi.ru/M6Q1LBRB

Comment: CGLContextObj context = CGLGetCurrentContext ();
context = NULL
turns out, there is no current context. And why in the main it is, but in the thread to create a new context?

Comment: Like I said, a context is current to _one thread_ at a time (at most). If you want it to be current in a different thread, you must make it current with [glx|wgl|cgl]MakeCurrent from there. GetCurrentContext does not do that, it only returns an identifier to the current context _if there is one_ (NULL otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL and multithreading are on difficult terms. It can be done, but it requires some care. First and foremost, a OpenGL context can be active in only one thread at a time. And on some systems, like Windows extension function pointers are per context, so with different contexts in different threads you may end up with different extension function pointers, which must be provisioned for.

So there's problem number one: You've probably got no OpenGL context on this thread, but this should not crash on calling a non-extension function, it would just do nothing.

If it really crashes on the line you indicated, then the `dh` pointer *is invalid* for sure. It's the only explanation. A pointer in C is just some number that's interpreted in a special way. If you pass around pointers – especially if used as a parameter to a callback, or thread function – then the object to pointer points to must not go invalid until it's made sure this pointer can no longer be accessed. Which means: You must not use this on things you create on the stack, i.e. in C auto storage.

This will break:

```
void foo(void)
{
    struct drawhandle dh_tmp;

    pthread_create(&posixThreadID, NULL, (void*(*)(void*))ShowThread, &dh_tmp);
}
```

why? Because the moment `foo` returns the object `dh_tmp` goes invalid. But `&dh_tmp` (the pointer to it) is just a number and this number will not "magically" turn zero, the moment `dh_tmp` gets invalid.

You must allocate it on the heap for this to work. Of course there's the problem, when to free the memory again.

Comment: I changed the code to
/ / glViewport (0, 0, dh-> swidth, dh-> sheight);
     glViewport (0, 0, 1280, 720);
the same error

Comment: @user1881371: That rules out this problem. So now you must make sure that you actually have a valid OpenGL context in the tread. See Damon's answer.